# Shell command for backup

Tags: shell, tomcat, putty

I have two directories com and ref. How do I backup all the files in com directory to the ref directory?

Also I want them compressed during backup. I also want to see by how much they have been compressed. What are the shell commands to do this?

PS: working on tomcat server using Putty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SRCDIR="/home/<username>/com/"
DESTDIR="/home/<username>/ref/"
FILENAME=ug-$(date +%-Y%-m%-d)-$(date +%-T).tgz
tar --create --gzip --file=$DESTDIR$FILENAME $SRCDIR
```

Comment: In some sense it working. However is there any simplified way of doing this?

Comment: That is the simplest way i know. If you have found my answer to be helpful and working for you, kindly accept it. Here are the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: This seems to copy the address of all files in the com directory and copy it into the ref directory.

Comment: Isn't that what you are looking for? What exactly do you mean by "backup"?

Comment: if the com directory have files a,b,c. I want these  files backed up into the ref directory. Now what Im getting is a txt file in the ref directory with the path for a,b,c.